Trouble Implementing Algolia Search in Docusaurus v2: Incomplete HTML Crawling and Limited Content Retrieval
I'm integrating Algolia search into a Docusaurus v2 project and encountering issues with the indexing process. The crawler seems to run successfully, but it fails to index the site properly.
Issues Encountered:
Incomplete HTML Crawling:
When testing the crawler in the Algolia editor, it appears to retrieve incomplete HTML. This suggests that the crawler might not be accessing the full content of the pages.
Limited Content Retrieval:
In the Monitoring section, I observed that each page request only retrieves 3,298 bytes of content. This seems unusually low and may indicate that the crawler is unable to access larger portions of the site content.
Every request could get only 3,298 bytes contents
Questions:

Has anyone faced similar issues with Algolia's crawler in Docusaurus v2?
What could be causing the incomplete HTML retrieval and limited content size?
Are there specific settings or configurations in Docusaurus or Algolia that I might be missing?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I've confirmed that the crawler settings in the Algolia dashboard are correctly configured for my Docusaurus site.
The sitemap and robots.txt do not restrict the crawler’s access.
